# Prove that the trace of the matrix product $U'AU$ is maximized by setting $U$'s columns to $A$'s eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an expression which I want to maximize:
$$\mbox{trace} (U^T\Sigma U)$$

$\Sigma \in R^{d \times d}$ is symmetric and positive definite
$U \in R^{d \times r}$ its columns are orthonormal.

I am following a proof which states that U is optimal when its columns are the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$:

let $\Sigma = V\Delta V^T$, the eigen-decomposition;
let $B=V^TU$

then:
$$U=VB$$
$$U^T\Sigma U= B^TV^TV\Delta V^TVB = B^T\Delta B$$
the last statement is mathematically correct. However, how does this proof to me that the columns of U are the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$?

For some background: I am trying to understand a derivation of PCA. The point is that when this trace is maximized the objective function will be minimized.

Comment: What is B and why are you using it? I gues that if you want U to have the eigenvectors as columns then U=V and you equation reduces to $trace{/Delta}$

Comment: Note: this question can also be easily answered using the [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that with your substitution, finding the optimal $B$ with orthonormal columns is equivalent to finding the optimal $V$.  What we're trying to maximize, then, is
$$
\operatorname{trace}(B^T\Delta B) = \sum_{i=1}^r b_i^T\Delta b_i
$$
Where $b_i$ is the $i$th column of $B$.  It turns out that the optimum occurs when each $b_i$ is a standard basis vector.

Because it's a result that makes *intuitive* sense, it's common to mistakenly assume that it's easy to prove.  See, for instance, the mistaken proof given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart.E2.80.93Young.E2.80.93Mirsky_theorem_.28for_Frobenius_norm.29).  Why is the result intuitive?  I think that's because it's clear that if we perform a *greedy* optimization one column $b_i$ at a time, then we'd arrive at the correct result.  However, I would say there's no (simple) a priori justification that this should give us the right answer.  If you look at the [original paper](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/eckart%26young.1936.pdf) deriving the results required for PCA, you'll see that the required proof takes some Lie-group trickery.

The most concise modern proof is one using the appropriate trace inequality.  I would prove the result as follows: to find an upper bound for the maximum, apply the [Von-Neumann trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Von_Neumann.27s_trace_inequality).  In particular, we have
$$
\operatorname{trace}(U^T\Sigma U) = 
\operatorname{trace}(\Sigma[UU^T]) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(\Sigma)\lambda_i(UU^T)
$$
where $\lambda_i(M)$ of a positive definite matrix $M$ denote the eigenvalues of $M$ in decreasing order.  Note that $UU^T$ is a projection matrix of rank $r$, so we have $\lambda_1(UU^T) = \cdots = \lambda_r(UU^T) = 1$ and $\lambda_{r+1}(UU^T) = \cdots = \lambda_n(UU^T) = 0$.  Conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^r\lambda_i(\Sigma)$ is an upper bound.

From there, it suffices to show that taking the columns of $U$ to be the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ (in the correct order) allows you to attain this upper bound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer =) took me a while to get back to your answer... (mid exam seesion)

Comment: At last something which makes sense of the proofs for PCA. Because some other approaches are just finding $ w $ which maximize $ {w}^{T} \Sigma w $. Now what I don't understand is how do they ignore (Or I'm mistaken) that the problem is maximizing a Convex function with respect to $ w $ (Since $ \Sigma $ is PSD to the least).

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is here

Comment: It should be noted that this result is also proven directly in Corollary 4.3.18 of Horn and Johnson's Matrix Analysis (first edition).

Answer (score 3):

To further add to @Omnomnomnom's answer:

The calculations you posted shows, that the original problem is equivalent to the case where you have a diagonal matrix $\Delta$ instead of a merely symmetric $\Sigma$. Note here, that your $B$ is again orthogonal. You can now solve this new problem

$$\max \lbrace {\rm tr} ( B^T \Delta B ) | B \in \mathbb{R}^{n,k}, \, B^t B={\rm Id}_k \rbrace,$$

which is a bit easier than the original, and the maximum will be the same. Also, to get the desired matrix you can then set $U=VB$.

It turns out that the maximum is the sum of the $r$ largest eigenvalues and that $B=(e_1,\ldots,e_r) \in \mathbb{R}^{n,r}$, which then yields $U = VB= (v_1,\ldots,v_r)$, where $v_i$ are ordered eigenvectors of $\Sigma$.

The author of the proof you are following suggests that the solution of the new maximization is obvious. However, Omnomnomnom and I do not agree with that. You could therefore take the approach shown in his or her answer, or you could try to finish your proof. This is actually quite tedious as I will try to show, so I'd suggest to use Omnomnomnom's proof or Nick's suggestion for the upper bound [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248198/maximizing-trace-of-vtav-for-a-symmetric-alternate-proof-with-min-max-theore).

In order to finish your proof, start by calculating
$${\rm tr} ( B^T A B ) = \sum_{j=1}^r \sum_{i=1}^n b_{i,j}^2 \lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^r b_{i,j}^2)\lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \lambda_i$$ where $B=(b_{i,j})$ and $h_i := \sum_{j=1}^r b_{i,j}^2$. You could also have arrived at this point by simply expressing the columns of $U$ as a linear combination of an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Now we'll show two properties of the above linear combination. For the first one, add columns to $B$ to build an orthogonal square matrix $C=[B|R]=(c_{i,j})$ and note that for each $i$

$$0 \le h_i = \sum_{j=1}^r b_{i,j}^2 = \sum_{j=1}^r c_{i,j}^2 \le \sum_{j=1}^n c_{i,j}^2 = 1$$

holds because $CC^T={\rm Id}_n$. Secondly, for the sum of the coefficients we have

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n h_i = \sum_{j=1}^r <b_j,b_j> = r \cdot 1 = r$$.

Now we've arrived at exactly [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/4813/max-of-a-convex-combination-over-a-convex-hull-of-real-variables) problem from convex optimization (with $a=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)^T$ and $x_{\min}=0$, $x_{\max}=1$). Instead of solving it with those methods, we can find the maximum by hand. We bound

$$\sum_{i=1}^n h_i \lambda_i \le \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} h_i \lambda_i + \lambda_r \sum_{i=k}^n h_i = \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} h_i \lambda_i + \lambda_r (r-\sum_{i=1}^{r-1}) = r \lambda_r + \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} h_i (\lambda_i - \lambda_r)$$.

Now we can establish an upper bound for our maximization problem:

$$\max \lbrace {\rm tr} ( B^T A B ) | B \in \mathbb{R}^{n,k}, \, B^t B={\rm Id}_k \rbrace \le \max \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \lambda_i | 0 \le h_i \le 1, \sum_{i=1}^n h_i = r \rbrace \\ \le \max \lbrace \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \lambda_i | 0 \le h_i \le 1\rbrace \le \max \lbrace r \lambda_r + \sum_{i=1}^{r-1} h_i (\lambda_i -\lambda_r) | 0 \le h_i \le 1\rbrace \le \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_k$$.

For the last inequality we've set $h_i=1$ since the term in brackets is nonnegative. Since this bound can be attained with $h_1 = \ldots = h_r = 1$ and $h_{r+1} = \ldots = h_n = 0$ we have found our maximum and with it the desired $B$ or $U$.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer! (Marked @Omnomnomnom's as the answer since he came first =/, wish I could accept both.... sorry)