# Understanding principal component analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, multivariable-calculus

Let $X$ be $m\times n$ sample matrix where each row is a sample point. We want to find matrix $P$ of dimension $n \times r$ such that $XP$ is the dimension reduced matrix of samples after applying the principal component technique.

We find $P$ by maximizing the trace of the covariance matrix $C_Y^{'}=\frac{1}{m}(XP)^T(XP)=P^T(\frac{1}{m}X^TX)P$. Because we want the variance of each variable to be maximized.

We let $C=\frac{1}{m}X^TX$ and we want to maximize $tr(P^TCP)$ subject to $P^TP=I$.

They said that we can use lagrange method to find partial of $f(P)=tr(P^TCP)+\lambda(P^TP-I)$. I don't understand this, please explain.

Also, they used $\frac{\partial tr(AB)}{\partial A}=B^T$, and $\frac{\partial X^TX}{\partial X}=X$. I need help understanding that as well.

They did $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}= \frac{\partial tr(P^TCP)}{\partial P}+\lambda \frac{\partial (P^TP)}{\partial P} =\frac{\partial tr(PP^TC)}{\partial P}+\lambda P=(P^TC)^T+\lambda P=C^TP+\lambda P=CP+\lambda P$, and when set to $0$, we get $CP=(-\lambda)P$.

And that shows why we need to calculate eigenvalues. I need clarification on that as well, for example, how to choose size of $P$?

Comment: I'm wondering, have you seen Lagrange multipliers before?

Comment: I've done some calculation with it in my cal3 class

Comment: Here, $\lambda$ is the vector of Lagrange multipliers for the constraint $P^TP=I$ (i.e. that $P$ is orthonormal). After taking derivatives and setting equal to 0, we see that they are actually the eigenvalues too. Take $r=1$ so that $\lambda$ is a scalar and it might become a little more clear.

Comment: In your Lagrangian $f(P)$, it should be $P^TP-I$, not $P^TP=I$, by the way. Happy to expand this into an answer if it's still confusing

Comment: I edited it. I don't understand how you can take partial with respect to $P$ as $P$ is a matrix. Please help me with an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, to continue from discussion in the comments. I think that the confusion could be that they are using the language of [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), which is just a compressed notation for taking derivatives with respect to elements of matrices, combined with [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), to derive PCA from what some people would call an "intuitive cost function." However, I think that the authors of what you are reading have been pretty hand-wavey and in fact what they wrote actually does not make much sense. Anyway...

So, there are kind of a couple of different questions that could be separated out here. A few of them will be handled better on their own, so I'll link to other SO answers in those cases.

#### Optimization problem

It seems like this part is pretty clear to you. We've set up an optimization problem: find $P$ to maximize the trace of $C_Y$
\[f(P) = \operatorname{tr}(P^T C P)\]
subject to the constraint that the columns of $P$ be orthonormal vectors, or in other words subject to\[P^TP=I.\]
Here $C=\frac{1}{m}X^TX$ is the empirical covariance of $X$ (usually after centering!).

#### Lagrangian

As written, the Lagrangian $f(P)$ can't be right -- you can see this by noticing that $P^TP-I$ is a matrix, so what is the value of the RHS supposed to be, also a matrix? We can try to fix it, but I want to argue that this is actually hard to do -- if you look at this answer:

- [Prove that the trace of the matrix product $U'AU$ is maximized by setting $U$'s columns to $A$'s eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902421/prove-that-the-trace-of-the-matrix-product-uau-is-maximized-by-setting-us?rq=1)

you'll see that it's not so simple to solve the problem, at least for $r>1$. I think that whoever wrote what you are working with was going for more of a qualitative understanding, and they seem to have ignored some of the complications for the sake of intuition, but this might be what was making things confusing.

In the $r=1$ case, it's not too hard. Our constraint just becomes $P^TP=1$, i.e. $P$ is really just a unit column vector. Then we get the Lagrangian

\[L(P,\lambda) = \operatorname{tr}(P^T C P) - \lambda (P^TP - 1).\]

This is not so hard to solve, and it gives the first principal component -- I'll show that in a second, but first I just want to note that extending this to more components is hard. The complications of doing that are addressed in the question I linked to above, but to get a feel, think about it: what are our constraints? We need all of the unit length constraints $P_i^T P_i=1$ for $i=1,\dots,r$ and all of the orthogonality constraints $P_i^TP_j=0$ for all $i,j$. But now we have more dual variables than were present in what you were given.

Anyway, back to $r=1$. To solve for $P$, take the derivative with respect to the vector $P$ and set equal to 0 using the vector analogies of the matrix calculus identities that you were given:
\[\frac{\partial L}{\partial P} = \frac{\partial \operatorname{tr}(P^T C P)}{\partial P} - \lambda \frac{\partial P^TP}{\partial P}.\]
Note that this is basically what you had above but with a sign change, since the Lagrangian should really be written how I have it here with the $-$ sign in front of $\lambda$. The vector partial derivatives here are just a different notation for gradients, so think of them that way if they are confusing. But the identities you wrote down hold and can help us solve this:

- The gradient $\frac{\partial\operatorname{tr}(P^TCP)}{\partial P}$ for $P$ and $B$ both column vectors is the row vector $2CP$.
- Similarly the derivative of a the dot product $P^T P$ with respect to $P_i$ is just $P_i$, so we can write the gradient with respect to the whole vector as $2P$ (factor of 2 because $P_i$ shows up on the right also).

Plugging in, we get
\[\frac{\partial L}{\partial P}= 2CP - 2\lambda P\]

Setting this equal to 0 to find the critical point, we get that $CP=\lambda P$, or in other words $P$ is an eigenvector of $C$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Now we have to optimize over $\lambda$, since it's still a free variable -- but to maximize $L(P,\lambda)$, we see that we just take the largest possible $\lambda$, but since we have learned that $\lambda$ must be an eigenvalue, that means taking the largest eigenvalue.

I hope this helped with some intuition, but understanding the full case with $r>1$ as I said earlier takes more work, I guess.

Comment: Good answer but please note you have some mistakes there in the algebra with the transposes and in the derivatives as well. When you derivate $\frac{\partial\mathrm{tr}(P^TB)}{\partial P}$ (I swapped the transposes to fit it then into $P^TCP$) you need to take into account that your $B$ is a function of $P$ as well. (Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3373521/283720).) You get a factor $2$ that eventually cancels with another one you missed in derivating $\frac{\partial P^TP}{\partial P}$ and the final result holds.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit those corrections in.